# Цикл останавливается после ввода первого элемента вектора

Tags: c++, for, vector

Пытаюсь в цикле заполнить вектор объектов класса и в том же цикле ввести значение переменной для каждого i-го объекта. Цикл останавливается после ввода первого числа (а их должно быть n, число n вводится с клавиатуры), и остальной код он просто игнорит.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std; 
class chislo {
    public:
    int znachenie;  
    map <int, int> razryady;
};
int main() 
{
    int n;
    cout << "Введите количество чисел " << "\n";
    cin >> n;
    
    vector <chislo> a;
    
    cout << "введите числа" << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i].znachenie;
        a.push_back(a[i]);
    }
   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читаем `n`, создаем ***пустой*** вектор

```
vector <chislo> a;
```

И пытаемся писать... куда?

```
cin >> a[i].znachenie;
```

Если ни одного `a[i]` в принципе не существует?

```
vector <chislo> a(n);
```

И еще... Вы говорите, что будете вводить `n`чисел. А сколько *реально* пытаетесь ввести?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
```